# Word for a person who often visits night clubs and bars?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Do I call them *clubbers* or are there better words to describe them?

Comment: Clubber is fine. It's a fairly new word that exists solely for that context. There are a good number of different words to describe different aspects of the behaviour of said person, but to simply state that they frequent clubs, 'clubber' is accurate. Similarly, there is the verb 'to club' or the gerund, '(go) clubbing' to describe the activity, though interestingly, that is much older.

Comment: @Karl, Thanks for informing that Clubber is fine. I thought there are better words than Clubber.

Comment: To be precise, you could call them a "frequent clubber".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word choice depends on what aspect of behavior you emphasize — drinking, dancing, talking loudly.

A *[carouser](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carouse)* is one who "engages in a noisy or drunken social gathering".

A *[reveller](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reveller)* is "one who revels; a party goer".  (To *[revel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revel)* is "to make merry; to have a gay, lively time", with *gay* meaning "happy, joyful, and lively".

Some far-less-specific words often used in the context of bar patrons are *regulars*, *[denizens](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denizen)* ("One who frequents a place. [*E.g.*]  The denizens of that pub are of the roughest sort."), and *[habitués](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habitu%C3%A9)* ("One who frequents a place; a denizen or regular [*E.g.*]     A month ago the new smoking ban turned thousands of bar-room habitues into reluctant exiles...")

Answer (score 2):

**clubber**

1. One that wields a club.
2. One who is active in a club.
3. One who frequents nightclubs.

It is a slang. The activity of frequently visiting bars and clubs is clubbing.

Comment: 'Clubber' is pretty much international.  I like to think of them as rounders "man of questionable morals who often “makes the rounds” of bars, bordellos"  -the latter defintion no longer necessary or required